# Sum subset query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subset

```
CREATE TABLE Test (id integer, name varchar(100), weight integer, turn integer);
INSERT INTO Test (id, name, weight, turn) VALUES (5, "George Washington", 250, 1);
INSERT INTO Test (id, name, weight, turn) VALUES (4, "Thomas Jefferson", 175, 5);
INSERT INTO Test (id, name, weight, turn) VALUES (3, "John Adams", 350, 2);
INSERT INTO Test (id, name, weight, turn) VALUES (6, "Thomas Jefferson", 400, 3);
INSERT INTO Test (id, name, weight, turn) VALUES (1, "James Elephant", 500, 6);
INSERT INTO Test (id, name, weight, turn) VALUES (2, "Will Johnliams", 200, 4);
```

The query should return a table containing exactly one record 'Thomas Jefferson' as the first three people will fit (in the order : George Washingthon, John Adams, Thomas Jefferson).  The sum of their weight is 250+350+400

The problem is I have to query where person will fit in elevator that can hold max <= 1000. how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a correlated subquery here to check the running weight total of people, given by the turn order:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Test t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(t2.weight) FROM Test t2 WHERE t2.turn <= t1.turn) <= 1000
ORDER BY t1.turn DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note: If you instead want all matching people within the weight limit, then just remove the `LIMIT` clause from the above query.