# Mysql - Sum of subset query with in a range

Tags: mysql

I have a table with sample data as follow:

```
| ID |        A |   B |
-----------------------
|  1 |      100 | 100 |
|  2 |      200 |  80 |
|  3 |      500 |   0 |
|  4 |      800 |   0 |
```

The goal is that I would like to have a SQL query which I can input a value and grab the rows of the Sum of the difference between a and b e.g.

Example 1.
if inputting 110
I will get first two rows with ids 2 due to  (100 - 100) + (200 - 80)  = 120 and 110 <= 120

Example 2.
if inputting 150
I will get first two rows with ids 2,3 due to  (100 - 100) + (200 - 80) + (500 - 0) = 620 and 150 <= 620

Example 3.
if inputting 620
I will get first two rows with ids 2,3 due to  (100 - 100) + (200 - 80) + (500 - 0) = 620 and 620 <= 620

Example 4.
if inputting 1000
I will get rows with ids 2,3,4 due to (100 - 100) + (200 - 80) + (500 - 0) + (800 - 0)= 1420 AND 1000 <= 1420

I have reference the query from
[Sum subset query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686981/sum-subset-query/51687144)

The answer is quite close but the result still cannot met with my scenario. May I know anyone have an idea what the statement will be to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use window functions for resolve your problem like:

```
select * from (
    -- get rolling sum for columns A & B
    select
      id,
      A,
      B,
      SUM(A-B) over(order by ID) as rsum
    from test
) sums
-- filter rows by value
having rsum <= 620
;
```

Example [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d35100f55878f3d662f3a2b781cef0c7&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and great appreciate for your help. Since my company servers are old and using MySQL 5.7, and there are different projects using that servers, so it may not be allowed to apply database upgrade. Do thanks on your solution, and I will try your solution in Mysql 8.0 first and see whether it can solve the problem.